# How to add Wordpress Featured image in <a> tag ..?

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, cms

I am trying to add Wordpress featured image in  tag. I used these 3 shortcodes.

```
<?php echo $image_large[0]; ?>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(null,'thumbnail');?>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'full' ); ?>
```

Example

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'full' ); ?>" >View Larger</a>
```

But nothing working. Please help me ...

Comment: You should call this method inside the loop, but your code is totally incomplete. Could you please add more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you're trying to echo the image into the href. What you want is just the URL to go there.

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $page->ID, 'full' )?>
```

You can learn more about this function [here in the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/).

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood your question correctly. You can try this.

```
    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
         <figure class="entry-thumb">
           <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
             <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', ['alt' => esc_html (get_the_title())]); ?>
           </a>
        </figure>
   <?php endif; ?>
```